# Add data into gridview retrieve from database based on gridview header

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some problems here.

How to begin to write `GridView` and insert data from the database manually one by one based on the `GridView` header?

I want to create `GridView` but the structure is not same in the database. So, I want to enter value from the database based on the `GridView` header. Is it possible?

Because, before this I only retrieved from the database all at once in the `GridView`. I did not know on how to retrieve based on the header `GridView`. I am a beginner in the C# language and hope you can give me some example on this? Thank you.

The following what I have done so far:

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request Date">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblReqDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("request_date") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A01"></asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A02"></asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "How to retrieve based on header" what do you mean by this ? You want only those columns from database ? Is grid view header changes in runtime ?

Comment: yes. i want the columns from database. but the gridview change structure in runtime. because the gridview display with database table display not same. for example i want to display A | B as gridview header but in database A | B is in one column which is Product. did you understand im talking about or you my explanation is bit confuse ?

Comment: You mean you have one column in database and you want to show it as two columns in grid right?

Comment: @Krishna yes true ! i want to show row in that one column database as different column in gridview.

Comment: You can split the data directly in database right ?

Comment: no i cant. any other solution instead of change database structure ?

Comment: You don't need to change structure, in the select statement split it. But if you want to do it in grid view add two columns and bind value in row databind

Comment: sory, can you give me some example. because im still beginner and do not know how to begin it :(

Comment: In database or in grid view which example ?

Comment: can you show me in gridview ?

Comment: Give me sample data from database only that column

Comment: request_date | no | product | quantity  : 8/5/2017 | 1 | A01 | 100, 9/5/2017 | 2 | A02 | 120. how to get value A01 and A02 become each column in gridview and the no and quantity is inside each of the column ? @Krishna

Comment: what is the value of A01 or A02 ? is there any separator to split ?

Comment: A01 and A02 is the row inside column product in database. i want A01 and A02 become each one column in gridview for ex : request date | A01 | A02. and value inside A01 and A02 is quantity and no retrieve from database

Answer (score 0):

Consider data your column has a semi-colon(;) as separator. Then do as below
Add template column with labels in them.

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView3_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request Date">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblReqDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("request_date") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A01">
                      <asp:Label ID="lblA01" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A02">
                      <asp:Label ID="lblA02" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now in data grid row bound split data and bind

```
protected void GridView3_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lblA01 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblA01");
        Label lblA02 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblA02");
        string val = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "product").ToString();
        string[] splittedData = val.Split(';');
        if (splittedData.Length > 0)
            lblA01.Text = splittedData[0];
            if (splittedData.Length > 1)
            lblA01.Text = splittedData[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps